# ORDER BY RATE - MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

IN my db has 2 tables:

**product table:**

```
---------------
 id  |  title
---------------
 1     Toyoto
 2     Lexux
```

**ratings table:**

```
----------------------------------------
rating_id  | rating | id | ip
----------------------------------------
     1          l      1    127.0.0.1
     2          d      1    127.0.0.2
     3          l      1    192.168.0.1
     4          l      2    192.168.0.1
-----------------------------------------
```

So Toyoto has 2 `l` (like) and 1 `d` (dislike). So I want to sort all product by likes and dislikes (sum like and dislike). In the last output will be:

```
Toyouto 3 votes and  Lexux 1 vote.
```

Order:

```
1. Toyoto
2. Lexux
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please ask a specific question, and show what you have tried already.  More information on using the site can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: This is a basic join and count, beginning stuff for any SQL programmer. SO is not a substitute for learning how to program, that's what schools are for.

Comment: Hint: create a subquery utilizing `GROUP BY id` on the `ratings` table, which tallies the likes and dislikes into a total score, then join that with your `product` table and sort.

Answer (score 1):

your query should be like this

```
Select title,count(r.rating) as votes 
from product as p Inner join rating as r on p.id=r.id 
where r.rating=1 
group by r.id`
```

Comment: what is r ? Is it ratings table?