# Order by rate in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, rate

IN my db has 2 tables:

**product table:**

```
---------------
 id  |  title
---------------
 1     Toyoto
 2     Lexux
```

**ratings table:**

```
----------------------------------------
rating_id  | rating | id | ip
----------------------------------------
     1          l      1    127.0.0.1
     2          d      1    127.0.0.2
     3          l      1    192.168.0.1
     4          l      2    192.168.0.1
-----------------------------------------
```

So Toyoto has 2 `l` (like) and 1 `d` (dislike). So I want to sort all product by likes and dislikes (sum like and dislike). In the last output will be:

```
Toyouto 3 votes and  Lexux 1 vote.
```

Order:

```
1. Toyoto
2. Lexux
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORDER BY RATE - MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462066/order-by-rate-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  products.title
FROM
  products INNER JOIN ratings
  ON products.id = ratings.id
GROUP BY
  products.id,
  products.title
ORDER BY
  SUM(ratings.rating='l')-SUM(ratings.rating='d')
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cd8f/2).

If you also want to show the rank number, you could use this:

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 as rank, title
FROM (
  SELECT
    products.title
  FROM
    products INNER JOIN ratings
    ON products.id = ratings.id
  GROUP BY
    products.id,
    products.title
  ORDER BY
    SUM(ratings.rating='l')-SUM(ratings.rating='d')
  ) s, (SELECT @rank:=0) r
```

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cd8f/3).

Comment: One moment, Shows only products, thoose have rate. How can do, shows product that has not rate(vote)

Comment: @serikshaikamalov you could use a left join instead of an inner join, it will return all products